# html & php question (get command)

Tags: php, get

Want to include another value in my urls

so far I have

```
   # valid pages
  $page = array('splash', 'portraits', 'weddings', 'studio', 'about', 'mobile',      'personal');

 # validate GET, default to splash if not provided
 $_GET['q'] = (isset($_GET['q'])) ? strtolower(trim($_GET['q'])) : 'splash';
 if (!in_array($_GET['q'], $page))
 $_GET['q'] = 'splash';

require_once "{$_GET['q']}.html";
```

but I want to include sections into my site so I need an extra value (ie. ?q=portraits?z=studio )

I assume I could probably just duplicate the $get command and replace q with z... but suppose I don't want the second value to be necessary (so the default pages will display without extra commands) and i want it to target a div or frame within the page? Not sure if I can even target divs.

Comment: Should be `?q=portraits&z=studio` not `?q=portraits?z=studio`. Also, your `if`statement in code is quite ambiguous. Wrap it with curly braces.

Comment: We know it's a "question", and we know it's about HTML/PHP. Can you improve your question title to actually describe the problem?

Comment: @user482594: It's not "ambiguous" in any way at all. (Hard to read, possibly.)

Answer (score 1):

Just use a default value:

```
if (isset($_GET['z'])) {
    $z = $_GET['z'];
}
else {
    $z = NULL; // or 'default' or whatever you want.
}
```

You can in short write the above in one line:

```
$z = isset($_GET['z']) ? $_GET['z'] : NULL;
```

I am not sure what you mean with "target a div", but if you mean an anchor, you can do that via identifiers (`id`).

Call your PHP script via `index.php?q=splash#text` and in your `splash.html` file you somewhere have `<div id="splash">`. The browser should scroll there.